# Http or .htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpd.conf, proxypass

I do have thousand of clients that have received a bad URL, and I am trying to rewrite it without success.

The bad url sent was:

```
http://www.123456.cl/123456-abcde/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/OrderDetailUserGuestView?storeId=10151&catalogId=10051&langId=-5&orderId=22172008&rut=10946497K
```

And the rewrite should redirect to:

```
http://www.123456.cl/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/OrderDetailUserGuestView?storeId=10151&catalogId=10051&langId=-5&orderId=22172008&rut=10946497K
```

Without the **123456-abcde**

All the contents after the view OrderDetail are dynamic.

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Sure do. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This: 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^123456-abcde/(.*)$ $1

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the right flags? And set a base?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^123456-abcde/(.*) $1 [L,R=301]
```

Try it without the `=301` (permanent) part, first. If it goes to the right place, make it permanent.